# bcc32 compiler and tlink32 linker options equivalent in linux for gcc and ld respectively

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++builder

I am trying to convert a legacy Delphi code from Windows to Linux. The Delphi project has some sub modules which are written in C and compiled using the bcc32 compiler and linked using the tlink32 linker.

As part of the Linux conversion of these C modules, I am planning to use the gcc compiler in place of bcc32, and the ld linker in place of tlink32.

But, I am finding it a bit difficult to find the equivalent compiler and linker flags/options in Linux. Below are the compiler (bcc32) and linker (tlink32) commands from the existing C code in Windows. It would be a great help if someone can suggest the equivalent flags for gcc and ld in Linux.

bcc32 compiler options:

> c:\bc45\bin\bcc32 -a1 -c -d -I..\..\_common\msgups -v- -w-aus -w-par -i50 -Dfar -DNO_SEGMENT_PRAGMA $(.SOURCE)

Here I am not able to find the gcc compiler flags corresponding to `-a1`, `-d`, `-v-`, `-w-aus`, `-i50`, `-Dfar`, `-DNO_SEGMENT_PRAGMA`

tlink32 linker options:

> c:\bc45\bin\tlink32 -s -n $(OBJ) $(.SOURCE), $@, $*.mup

Here I am not able to find the ld compiler flags corresponding to `-s` and `-n`

Comment: Please remove tag Delphi. Your question is really about C.

Comment: Please extend your question (by [edit]ing) and tell us what each of the options means. We are not going to look for a manual for Delphi, read it, do the same with GCC, and compare both. This is your task. If you happen to find an option that you don't know how to interpret or to map to a GCC option, list it, please.

Comment: This looks vey strangely similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379864/what-are-the-gcc-compiler-options-for-the-below-flags-used-for-bcc32 . That question was closed - the asker did not do any research. What research did you do? Did you check `bcc32` documentation to see what do these flags do? I know gcc - but I have no idea about bcc32. What do these options do?

Answer (score 1):

### bcc32 flags

Based on: [Using the Borland 5.5 Compiler and command-line tools](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20997),
[BCC32.EXE, the C++ 32-bit Command-Line Compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_32-bit_Command-Line_Compiler), and [Compiler Errors And Warnings (C++) Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Errors_And_Warnings_(C%2B%2B)_Index)

- `-aN` = Align on N bytes

  - thus, `-a1` is 1-byte alignment
- `-c` = Compile only, no link
- `-d` = Merge duplicate strings
- `-I` = Include files directory

  - thus, `-I..\..\_common\msgups` points to the `..\..\_common\msgups` folder
- `-v` = Source level debugging

  - thus, `-v-` disables debugging
- `-wxxx` = Warning control

  - thus:

    - `-w-aus` suppresses [warning #8004](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/W8004_%27identifier%27_is_assigned_a_value_that_is_never_used_(C%2B%2B)) ('identifier' is assigned a value that is never used)
    - `-w-par` suppresses [warning #8057](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/W8057_Parameter_%27parameter%27_is_never_used_(C%2B%2B)) (Parameter 'parameter' is never used)
- `-iN` = Max identifier length

  - thus, `-i50` is a max identifier length of 50
- `-Dxxx` = Define macro

  - thus:
  - `-Dfar` defines `far`
  - `-DNO_SEGMENT_PRAGMA` defines `NO_SEGMENT_PRAGMA`

### tlink32 flags

Based on: [Command-Line Options of LINK.EXE and TLINK32.EXE](https://flylib.com/books/en/4.288.1.27/1/)

- `-s` = Include detailed information about the segments in the MAP file.
- `-n` = no default library

Comment: Thanks for the links of bcc32 compiler. Actually I was not able to find a good documentation for bcc32. Your answer helped me lot. I have the documentation for gcc, now it will be more easy for me to search the gcc documentation to find the equivalent.